# How can I run Labeled LDA over one textual document?

Tags: nlp, supervised-learning, topic-model, lda

I have 200K tweets and I already a applied the LDA (Latent Dirichlet Allocation) algorithm using Gensim python library. And now I need to apply over them the **labeled/supervised LDA**. Can any one help me the steps of this task that I should follow. Otherwise, I will be thankful if you can provide me another python library to do so.

Comment: Strictly, that's one corpus with 200K documents.

Answer (score 1):

A [python package](https://github.com/strin/BayesPA) that you can check. It's an online max-margin topic model.